# Javascript replace with regular expression not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm having some javascript issues with some legacy code, since my company is attempting to upgrade to IE11 from IE8. I have a piece of javascript that finds all commas in a field and replaces it with a couple characters, it is as follows:

```
document.frm.txt_fieldValue[1].value = 
document.frm.txt_fieldValue[1].value.replace(/,/gi, "$0");
```

In my code this is all on one line, however. This code works in IE8, Chrome, and Firefox. However, in IE9+, specifically IE11 (since this is what my company is upgrading to), this code doesn't replace any commas. I can get it to replace a single comma by using the following code:

```
document.frm.txt_fieldValue[1].value = 
document.frm.txt_fieldValue[1].value.replace(",", "$0");
```

Because I replaced a single comma, I know my code is reached. But I have searched around and I have yet to find a solid answer. Does anyone else have this problem? If so, has anyone found a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle?  Additionally, maybe it is an assignment issue. Try var myValue=document.frm.txt_fieldValue[1].value.replace(/,/gi, "$0"); 
document.frm.txt_fieldValue[1].value = myValue;

Comment: Have you tried to escape the comma?

Comment: @E.Maggini I've never used Jfiddle. Trying to get it to work. I did try the assignment value, but that didn't work.

Comment: @MarcoCI I can try that. That does seem to work. It will require a decent rewrite of the page, but it should work. Thanks!

Comment: I meant to use something like `string.replace(/\,/gi, "$0");`. From a quick test it looks to work for me.

Comment: @MarcoCI Ah I see. I tried it, and it doesn't work for me. I'm wondering if it is less IE11 and more the code I have inherited.

Comment: I'm confused--you're replacing the command with `$0`, which is....the comma you just matched. What is this regexp supposed to do? You say "replace with a couple of characters", but you're replacing it with `$0`, which is the matched string...did you mean to escape the `$`, which would be `$$`?

Comment: @torazaburo Here's what the asp page is supposed to do (in short form), take all the inputs in the form, replace all the commas in every input and textarea with the string "$0" (without quotes), and place all the forms into one large comma delimited string when the form gets posted. The page then reads the comma delimited string, parses it, replaces the "$0" with commas again, and outputs the values on the page again.

Comment: Then you have to replace it with `"$$0"`. I doubt if this code ever worked properly, on any browser.

Comment: @torazaburo That totally fixed it! Thank you so much man. I dunno if it never worked on any browser, but it certainly stopped working when we moved to IE11. I personally think the real flaw here is the design. The developer shouldn't have put all the text into a giant comma delimited string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace it with "$$0", which after escaping will turn into a real `$0`. I doubt if this code ever worked properly, on any browser.

Answer (score 1):

I recently fixed a bug that might help.

If your value that you were replacing was 0 -- as a value, not a string -- IE11 would only append the replacement string instead of actually replacing it.

Here's what I was working with:

```
buf = buf.replace( /%%TOTALAMOUNT%%/gim, "$" + parseFloat( g_UserPurchases[LCV].CurrencyValue.val() ).toFixed(2) );
```

This printed: "**%%TOTALAMOUNT%%.00**"

I fixed it by checking:

```
if( ( g_UserPurchases[LCV].CurrencyValue.val() == 0 ) || ( g_UserPurchases[LCV].CurrencyValue.val() === 0 ) ){
//IE fix: IE did not like the $ character and didn't replace if val = 0
buf = buf.replace( /%%TOTALAMOUNT%%/gim, "&#36;0.00");    }
```

Please note: IE11 didn't replace the the dollar sign character, $. So, I used the character code instead:

```
&#36;
```

Hope this helps!